# Is there an MMC Snap-In available for Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer?

Tags: windows

I tried looking up for it. Couldn't find one so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MBSA is a stand-alone tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/cc184923), it's not part of the MMC.